# Upload image using OpenFileDialog and move/cut the image from its original location to another location

Tags: vb.net

Please help. How could i transfer the image to another location using vb.net?

i've tried this strategy but its not working.

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.Click
    If dlg.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        fullPath = dlg.FileName 'c:\Sample\image1.jpg
        ImageFileName = Path.GetFileName(dlg.FileName) 'image1.jpg filename holder
        PathHolder = Path.Combine("d:\FinalLocation", ImageFileName)
        With PictureBox2
            .Image = Image.FromFile(fullPath )
            .SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

THEN When user click save button i have a code like this

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    File.Move(fullPath, PathHolder) 'the 1st try
    'System.IO.File.Move(fullPath, PathHolder) '2nd try but its not working at all
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is so easy. Your code is correct but there is 1 line is missing in the save button.

Try to add this:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
picturebox2.image.dispose()
File.Move(fullPath, PathHolder)
End Sub
```

I think you cannot move the image to another location because it is still in use by the picturebox.

Just give it a try :)

Comment: yah its works. i already try that kind of strategy but instead of dispose i use picturebox2.image = Nothing and still cause an error. thanks to you now i know that i can also use dispose in picture box